# How to Detect a collition during animation?

Tags: android, android-animation

I successfully made an arrow to move along a pre-defined path. Now i want to place some randomly moving object in the path and want to detect weather the arrow hits the object or not. The following is the code which i'm using for animation.

```
    public void doAnimation(){
        Matrix mxTransform=new Matrix();
        PathMeasure pm=new PathMeasure(path,false);
        float fSegmentLen = (float)((pm.getLength())/50);
        if(iCurStep<=50){
            pm.getMatrix(fSegmentLen * iCurStep, mxTransform,
                    PathMeasure.POSITION_MATRIX_FLAG + PathMeasure.TANGENT_MATRIX_FLAG);
             canvas.drawBitmap(bt, mxTransform, null);
             iCurStep++;
             invalidate();
        }
        else{           
            iCurStep=0;
            animate=0;
            canvas.drawPoint((float)range-10,0f,forPoint);
        }
    }
```

The variable iCurStep is declared globally and the above function will be called inside the onDraw() method. I'm a beginner to android. So its very difficult for me to code. So I'm kindly requesting you to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way as get the `current position` of the `Arrow` and `moving objects`.At any point of time, check its x-ordinates of Arrow `intersects` with x-coordinates of moving object.And similarly check for its y co-ordinates as well.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you but actually i'm drawing the arrow through a bitmap using a matrix. I'm not having clear understanding about the Matrix in android. So i think its difficult for me to detect the x and Y co-ordinates of the bitmap. Please Help me